# Replacing a repetative phrase with increasing numbers

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Hi I am looking for a command line solution to replace the '1' value in each line I have with ascending values. My input looks like:

```
K   X   1
K   X   1
K   X   1
K   X   1
K   X   1
K   X   1
K   X   1
K   X   1
K   X   1
K   X   1
```

and I would like the output to be

```
K   X   1
K   X   2
K   X   3
K   X   4
K   X   5
K   X   6
K   X   7
K   X   8
K   X   9
K   X  10
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Are the numbers always the last field of the file? The number 10 was displaced to the left: Is that necessary/correct or a mistake?

Answer (score 4):

This may be an option with `awk`:

```bsh
$ awk '$3 = $3+i++' file
K X 1
K X 2
K X 3
K X 4
K X 5
K X 6
K X 7
K X 8
K X 9
K X 10
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want lines of input to be renumbered sequentially, you can use the awk *record number*, `NR` ex.

```
awk '{printf "%s%4s%4d\n", $1, $2, NR}' input
```

Answer (score 0):

My Bash solution (untested, and it assumes that K and X don't contain white space):

```
i=1
while read a b c
do 
  echo $a $b $i
  i=$((i+1))
done < inputfile
```

Correct output formatting is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: If you copy/paste that into http://shellcheckcheck.net it'll tell you about some of the issues with it. See also [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for others.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '$3=NR' file
K X 1
K X 2
K X 3
K X 4
K X 5
K X 6
K X 7
K X 8
K X 9
K X 10
```

Fore! :-)